# Problems with void function in header of my static library

Tags: c++, header, static-libraries, void

I'm programming a .lib file for mobile robot.
Among other commands regarding robot movement, I also have command for scanning for Bluetooth devices looking something like:

```
void ScanForDevices(vector<Device> &Robot)
{
    /* code for searching Bluetooth devices and saving their names and addresses into vector of Device struct*/
}
```

My question is related with writing the header of the .lib file.

One of my commands is:

```
string RobotMove(int Translation, int Rotation)
    {
            /* create Command
        return string(Command);
    }
```

In the header, for that command I have:

```
// Returns MOVE command
        std::string RobotMove(int Translation, int Rotation);
```

What I have problem with is what to write in the header for:

```
void ScanForDevices(vector<Device> &Robot)
```

I keep getting "Incomplete type is not allowed" is I try to do the same way as RobotMove command. Do I have to declare in some way in the header struct Device?

Comment: You probably need to `#include <vector>` or the header for `Device`.

Comment: I have included <vector>. Must be the Device header then. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to declare in some way in the header struct Device?

If you want to create vectors for `Device`s, you need to let compiler know the size of the class by defining it. As noted by BoBTFish, the usual way is to just include `Device.h` header (or similar).

If you use pointers (`vector<Device*>` or even better, appropriate kind of smart pointer: `vector<shared_ptr<Device>>`) forward declaration (just stating `class Device;`) would be enough, as compiler knows size of the pointer on your architecture. *(Note that this is completely different approach with different semantics than in your question, and this is just a side-note).*

Comment: @Angew yeah - I've noted that few seconds before the comment! Thank you for the suggestion - I will add additional note!

Comment: Thank you Nemanja. So, using my approach, I have to create header Device.h in which I describe struct. After that I include Device.h into library header?

Comment: @page47250 You're welcome! Yes - that is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I'll try it when I get to my computer and then I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: I did all of the steps (created header devices->described struct->included header devices in header of my .lib). Everything is working until in lib header I write `void ScanForDevices(vector<Device> &Robot)`. Until then when I type in `vector` intellisense recognizes vector keyword. After `void ScanForDevices(vector<Device> &Robot)` for vector reports that it's unknown type and intellisense doesn't recognize it anymore. I have `#include <vector>` in lib header.

Comment: @page47250 Try with `std::vector<Device>`. Also, intellisense is not very good when it comes to parsing C++ - try to compile your library.

Comment: And what about `std::vector<Device>`?

Comment: I'm currently at work. I'll try it as soon as I get home. Inače, hvala za pomoć.

Comment: `vector` is defined in `std` namespace, so if you don't have `using namespace std;` in your header file (and you should not have that), you need to refer it directly. Nema na čemu :).

Answer (score 0):

if your header file does not include (directly or indirectly),a definition for vector class you need to add `#include <vector>`  to your header file. The compiler does not know this data type without providing it the right information.